Появилось окно "Вы заработали доступ к очереди Голоса за переоткрытие!"
А мне это точно должно показываться? Ведь доступ к очередям получен уже давным-давно.


Мои поздравления!

В принципе, это может говорить о том, что ты очень давно не заходил в эту очередь. По крайней мере с момента, когда это окошко добавили.

Подобные окошки с информацией об очередях проверок были добавлены в апреле 2021. Я тогда задавал вопрос как можно отобразить это окно еще раз, если однажды его закрыл: How to see Review Queue help boxes again?
Вероятно, ты просто не посещал эту очередь с тех пор. Или же сбросил флажки, блокирующие отображение этих окошек, как указано в ответе по приведённой мной ссылке.
Долнительно выполнил перевод последнего предложения. Будет на сайте в новых сборках, текущая 2024.10.29.17670.

Что-то сомнительно, чтобы 3 года не заходил...

@Qwertiy можно, наверное, запрос в SEDE сделать, ну или глазами посмотреть, инфомация ведь публична о проверках.

Хм.. Странно, но ладно...
